# How do I automatically load a header and footer view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am new to using CodeIgniter but I do have enough understanding on mvc structure and CodeIgniter itself to do simple things like load views in the controller and auto load libraries e.c.t. But the issue I'm having is I have a header and footer view that I want to be loaded automatically every time I load a view file.

I have done some searching and a lot of suggestions are dated, or sometimes I simply don't understand the solution. I have made my header view and linked my CSS in it, and also created my footer view as well. So lets say I wanted to load the default welcome page like below:

```php
public function index() {
      $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

I can load them manually like so:

```php
public function index() {
      $this->load->view('common/header');
      $this->load->view('welcome_message');
      $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```

But what I would like is to just load the view like normal and have my header and footer loaded with it automatically. I understand this needs to be accomplished using a custom library with a template function of some sort, but I don't know enough to just do that from scratch.

Comment: why not you are using base controller and load header and footer from there ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this and it works for me.

**MY_Loader.php**

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader{
    public function template($content,$var=array()){
        $this->view('common/header');
        $this->view($content,$var);
        $this->view('common/footer');
    }
}
```

Put it in `core` folder.

In your controller :

```
 public function index(){
   $content = "welcome_message";
   $data = array();
   $data['name'] = "Max";
   $data['country'] = "USA";
   $this->load->template($content,$data);
 }
```

Call the data in view :

```
<html>
  <?php echo $name.' - '.$country; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah brilliant nice and simple! How do you pass data through though? would I need to add a second paramater to the template function for any data being passed through?

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago but using this doesn't allow me to put view files in subfolders in the main view folder, is there a remedy to this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a core controller class called `MY_Controller` and make every controller extends this controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function render($view)
    {
        $this->view('layouts/header', $this->data);
        $this->view($view, $this->data);
        $this->view('layouts/footer', $this->data);
    }

}
```

Now in your controller:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = 'Welcome Home';
        $this->render('welcome_view');
    }

}
```